# Creating input on the fly jquery and setting its value from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, count, counter

I have two item on my first table, Apple and Banana.
So i need to create two input which counts the number of duplicate on the second table. But I ended up creating three input :

See this for [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ocaomc8k/2/)

```
Apple : value is 1
Banana : value is 1 
Banana : value is 2
```

Can anyone check my logic and loop, basically I just need to create an input naming by its item on the first table and the value of it should be the last value of this `duplicateCounter` variable.

This is my wanted output :

```
Apple : value is 1 // last value of duplicate counter for Apple
Banana : value is 2//  last value of duplicate counter for Banana
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the code in if condition to:

```
  duplicateCounter++;
  $('#form1:not(:has(.'+$tds2.eq(0).val()+'))').append(''+ $tds2.eq(0).val() +'<input class="'+$tds2.eq(0).val()+'" type="text" name = '+ $tds2.eq(0).val()+' value = '+duplicateCounter+' /><br />');
  $('.'+$tds2.eq(0).val()).val(duplicateCounter)
```

**## Demo**

Comment: can  you please do it without the label part and just set the class to input?, Im having difficulty to read your code.Thanks a lot.